# [c++]: problem about initiation list in constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, initializer-list

I stumbled across a question that I never thought about before.
Here it is:
each object's (listed in the initialization list) "**constructor**" will be triggered.

```
class B
{
    public:
        B() { cout<<"B Con\n";}
        B(const B &b) { cout<<"B Copy Con\n";}
};

class A
{
    public:
        A(B &b):_m(b) { cout<<"A Con\n";}
        A(const A &a):_m(a._m) { cout<<"A Copy Con\n";}
    private:
        B _m;
}

main()
{
    B b;
    A a(b);
}
```

then I got the output as follows:

```
B Con
B Copy Con
A Con
```

According to the output, I think, 'A a(b)' triggered B's copy constructor.
If I got right, then that means 'A(B &b):_m(b)' triggers B's **copy constructor**.
Why not constructor but copy-constructor?

Comment: It can chose between B() and B( B const&), and you pass it a B... so which will be chosen?

Comment: ya, I think I was confused by some kinda stupid thought. I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is when you call

```
_m( whatever )
```

then the copy constructor

```
B(const B &b)
```

is the only one that could match the parameter list. You pass it one parameter and that parameter is of type `class B`.

Copy constructor is not something super special - it is just a parameterized constructor that will be invoked via the initialization list once the parameter list matches.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're telling the compiler to initialize `_m` with `b`, how would that not call the copy constructor?

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the    `A(B &b):_m(b)` You are instantiating B _m with the copy constructor.

If instead you did     `A(B &b):_m()` it would use the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
A(B &b):_m(b) { cout<<"A Con\n";}
```

Here `_m(b)` causes invocation of `B(const B&)` which is B's copy-constructor. That is why, it first prints `B Copy Con` when initializing `_m`, then it enters into A's constructor body, and prints `A Con`. That explains it all.

Comment: yes, I think I was confused just now, Now I got it. A stupid question.